# Flutter: Save the color of correct answer to become persistent when the app is closed and reopened again

Tags: flutter

[Image of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX4QN.jpg)

**Here is the Code**

As I said in the question I want to make the color of choice persistent when the person choose it and close the app and reopen it again. I tried sharedPreferences but it fails and i dont know why. so please help me solve out this problem. This is my code.

```
class Answers extends StatefulWidget {
  final List questionAnswers;
  Answers(this.questionAnswers);

  @override
  _AnswersState createState() => _AnswersState();
}

class _AnswersState extends State<Answers> {
  var isSelected = false;

  void onTap() {
    setState(() {
      isSelected = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ...widget.questionAnswers.map((answer) {
          return InkWell(
            onTap: onTap,
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 10),
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8, left: 10, right: 12),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: isSelected
                    ? answer["isCorrect"]
                        ? Colors.green.shade200
                        : Colors.red.shade200
                    : Colors.transparent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                ),
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text("${answer["code"]})"),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Text(answer["answerText"]),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how does using sharedPreferences fail? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: also in general, I'm assuming you mean you want to save if the answer is correct or not, right? wouldn't you want to use some kind of database for that or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: yes, I want to save the correct answer  with its green color. so what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use shared preferences to save which answer is the selected one do this:
(there shouldn't be any reason this doesn't work)

add in your pubspec.yaml file:

(under dependencies like this )

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
```

then in the file where you want to save and retrieve the data:

```
    import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

then to set data you need to initialize the shared preferences, one way to do this is like this, where the shared preferences is a data member of the state:

```
  initializeAsync() async {
    this.sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeAsync();
    super.initState();
  }
```

then the code will await for the shared preferences to be initialized when you initialize the state, and when it's done initializing launch a build of the widget tree again (this is incase you want to use the shared preferences stored data in your build function.

Anyhow, in order to save the data:
lets say that you have a variables named questionIdentifier and answerIdentifier (can be just the text of the question and answer)

just save 1 if its selected (when tapped) and 0 for the others

```
await sharedPreferences.setInt("$questionIdentifier_$answerIdentifier", 1);
```

then you can read the value when building (the 0 is the default value):

```
int isSelected = sharedPreferences.getInt("$questionIdentifier_$answerIdentifier") ?? 0;
```

just in the beginning of your build function make sure this.sharedPreferences is initialized by making sure it isn't null and if it is, return a loading widget or just an empty
Container()

The logic behind it is that shared preferences receives a key/value pair on "set" and a key on "get", so you just have to create a unique string key for each question/answer combo and store a value on whether or not its selected.

another approach might be to save just a key for an answer and in the value store the number of the currently chosen answer (as long as you can only choose one)

Hope i helped! :)